# Search using linq and dropdowns

Tags: asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu

I got about 5 look-a-like linq querys just like this `SortPerson()` metod. I'm trying to develop a search using dropdowns where a user can select values from the dropdown and returns the values that are true from one or more dropdowns the user has selected to use.

Is there a simpler way to develop this? help would be much appreciated

```
public void SortPerson()
{
    var personId = ddlPerson.SelectedValue;
    var data = new MyModelContext();

    var documents = from d in data.tblDocuments
                    join sp in data.tblPersons on d.DocPerson equals sp.PersonId
                    select d;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(personId))
    {
        documents = documents.Where(c => c.DocPerson.Equals(personId));
    }

    rptResult.DataSource = documents.ToList();
    rptResult.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "values that are true"?

Comment: True is not right word for it! An eksampel off that i want is like this page www.fg.fo/index.asp?pID={DA41DFD0-84F3-4641-9300-AE4E9591A9E4} You wont understand the language, but you will understand the funktionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point in joining without `Where` if you still select only one table.

If you want all document in case when Person is not selected, then you can't create much simpler method. You can write it shorter like:

```
var documents = 
  from d in data.tblDocuments
  join ...
  where String.IsNullOrEmpty(personId) || d.DocPerson equals personId
  select d;
```

so you don't need separate `if` statement.

If you want to use several values from 5 dropdowns and use them as conditions in single query, just add more conditions:

```
var personId = ddlPerson.SelectedValue;
var someValue = ddlSomeDDL.SelectedValue;
//3 more values from DDL

var documents = from d in data.tblDocuments
                join sp in data.tblPersons on d.DocPerson equals sp.PersonId
                where (String.IsNullOrEmpty(personId) || sp.PersonId equals personId)
                && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someValue) || d.SomeColumn equals someValue)
                //3 more conditions
                select d;
```

Comment: wont i get Input string was not in a correct format. if the dropdown is emtey?

Comment: `var personId = ddlPerson.SelectedValue;`

Now personId will be wither null or string value.